# Check if non-free firmware has been installed correctly

Tags: debian, debian-installer, firmware

I downloaded the deb packages; put them, without extracting them, into a USB drive* and, when asked, I told the installer to search them in that drive.

Now, on my freshly installed system, the files the installer told me that were missing are in `/lib/firmware`, but `dpkg -s <package>` says the packages are not installed. Is it ok?

*I did so because [the guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch06s04.html.en) says: "If the firmware was loaded from a firmware package, debian-installer will also install this package for the installed system and will automatically add the non-free section of the package archive in APT's sources.list. This has the advantage that the firmware should be updated automatically if a new version becomes available." It's not clear whether the package should be uncompressed, I decided to leave it as it was.

---

The firmware packages in question are [`firmware-brcm80211`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-brcm80211) and [`firmware-realtek`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-realtek). The missing firmware files are `brcm/bcm43xx-0.fw` and `rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw`.

Comment: You should extract the firmware then copy it to the usb drive , it will be loaded during the sys install. Can you add the `.deb` file to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You should extract the `.deb` file then copy it to your USB drive , when you are asked to load the missing firmware , plug in the USB, there is an example :

```
mkdir bcm && cd bcm
wget  http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-brcm80211_20161130-3_all.deb
ar x firmware-brcm80211_20161130-3_all.deb
tar xvf data.tar.xz
cd /lib/firmware/brcm
ls
```

sample output:

```
bcm43xx-0.fw              brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin    brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin
bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw          brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin   brcmfmac43569.bin
brcmfmac43143.bin         brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin    brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin
brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin    brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin    brcmfmac43570-pcie.bin
brcmfmac43236b.bin        brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin   brcmfmac43602-pcie.ap.bin
brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin  brcmfmac4339-sdio.bin    brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin  brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin   brcmfmac4366b-pcie.bin
brcmfmac43241b5-sdio.bin  brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin   brcmfmac4371-pcie.bin
```

Copy the `bcm43xx-0.fw` to your USB drive. repeat the same steps for the `rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw`

---

The firmware package= `firmware-realtek`

> If the firmware was loaded from a firmware package, debian-installer will also install this package for the installed system and will automatically add the non-free section of the package archive in APT's sources.list. This has the advantage that the firmware should be updated automatically if a new version becomes available.

loose firmware files =`rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw`

> If the firmware was loaded from loose firmware files, the firmware copied to the installed system will not be automatically updated unless the corresponding firmware package (if available) is installed after the installation is completed.

Comment: So you say I should put the individual files in the root of my usb key? Doesn't that put me in the case where "If the firmware was loaded from loose firmware files, the firmware copied to the installed system will not be automatically updated unless the corresponding firmware package (if available) is installed after the installation is completed."?

Comment: @ArchStanton You should reinstall the 2 package after the installation is completed. this steps is to get the internet working during the system install

Comment: Well, my wi-fi worked anyway, so I was wondering if I did anything wrong that caused the packages to figure as not installed.

Comment: @ArchStanton You are not installed the 2 packages yet , you are used only the wifi firmware to get the wifi/ethernet working , the `apt` and `dpkg` cannot see and identify the 2 packages .

Comment: So, can I conclude that I did it right and now I should just install the packages? (Note that I have the uncompressed packages in `/lib/firmware`.) But then why does the guide say that the "debian-installer will also install this package for the installed system" if it really doesn't? Sorry but I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Thanks for your help GAD3R, anyhow, I'm not accepting your answer because I still don't understand: is it okay to put .deb archives in the usb drive? Do the files in `/lib/firmware` mean that the packages have been found and installed but the package manager lost track of them? Is the guide wrong, i.e. do I have to install the packages anyway after installing Debian?